# Почему вылезает Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c, cs50

Начала писать программу, где в самом начале пользователь должен ввести 1 аргумент командной строки в виде положительного числа. При вводе чего угодно кроме `./caesar` выдает `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Пробовала без вызова функции `only_digits` внутри `main` прописывать тот же цикл, тогда все работает как надо. Но в задаче стоит создать эту функцию. Есть подозрения, что проблема возникает из-за того, что я вообще не понимаю, что эта функция должна возвращать (запуталась с нулями и единицами). Но я пробовала и return 0, и return 1 - исход одинаковый. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста...

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int only_digits(string argv[1]);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // If the number of CLA is more or less than two
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("User: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int digit = only_digits(&argv[1]);

    string plaintext = get_string("Please enter the message you want to code here: ");

}

int only_digits(string argv[1])
{
    // If the 2nd CLA is not an integer
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("User: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: давайте переменным осмысленные имена, избавьтесь от `string` и `get_string` (которые еще и не объявлены), от копипасты и начните следить за выходом за пределы массива

Comment: @user7860670 там библиотеку `cs50.h` юзают. в которой `typedef char * string ;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я в курсе, однако в примере это лишнее.

Comment: @user7860670 не могли бы вы пояснить, каким переменным в этом коде надо дать осмысленные имена? И про какую копипасту речь...

Comment: `argv[1]` осмысленно используется только в `main`, а скопипасчено 4 раза

Comment: @user7860670 вы о том, что лучше заменить на какую-то переменную, чтобы не повторять везде argv[1]?

Comment: @user7860670 про выходы за пределы массива я видела ответы, когда гуглила этот вопрос, но в упор не вижу, где я за его пределы выхожу и почему выхожу именно при выносе цикла в отдельную функцию... Поэтому и написала сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В

```c
 int digit = only_digits(&argv[1]);
```

вы передаёт указатель на аргумент. А в функции вы добавляете ещё раз индекс `[1]`

```c
strlen(argv[1])
```

Локальная переменная `argv` **уже** указывает на первый элемент и дополнительное смещение укажет на нулевой указатель. Происходит крах памяти.

Подробнее в функции `main` так :

```
argv [ ] = [0] = адрес0 , [1] = адрес1 , [2] = адрес2

адрес0 = "има проги"
адрес1 = "аргумент"
адрес2 = нулевой указатель

& argv [ 1 ] == & адрес1
```

а в `only_digits` локальная переменная :

```
argv == & адрес1
argv + 1 == & адрес2
argv [ 1 ] == адрес2
```

Простое решение - поменять индекс на ноль :

```c
int only_digits(string argv[])
{
    // If the 2nd CLA is not an integer
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[0]); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[0][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("User: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

А лучше передавать не указатель на массив строк, а указатель на одну строку.

```c
int only_digits(string argv);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // If the number of CLA is more or less than two
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("User: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int digit = only_digits(argv[1]);

    //string plaintext = get_string("Please enter the message you want to code here: ");
  string plaintext = "привет" ;
}

int only_digits(string argv)
{
    // If the 2nd CLA is not an integer
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("User: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я про это не знала!

Comment: Ну вот, у человека был шанс самостоятельно разобраться и чему-то научится... И если уж пишите, то стоило бы написать про бессмысленность передачи указателя на указатель и последующего индексирования.

Comment: @user7860670 буду признательна, если подскажете мне тему, на которую стоит почитать, чтобы разобраться в этом получше. Я готова разбираться, просто в интернете информации очень много, а лишнюю читать времени нет совсем. Хотелось бы найти информацию по существу, чем тратить время на отсеивание ненужной.